# ffmpeg / ffprobe gives creation_time 1970 but actual timestamp is correct

Tags: linux, bash, video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'd gotten some video recorded from a surveillance cam, and in the recording itself, the correct timestamp is clearly shown in a corner.

I wanted to extract the creation time from the video metadata, however ffmpeg (and ffprobe) both give me creation_time as `creation_time:1970-01-01T00:33:37.000000Z` (i.e the unix epoch time)

(tested with `ffmpeg -i <video>` and `ffprobe -v quiet -print_format compact -show_entries format_tags=creation_time <video>`, where `<video>` is the location of video)

Any way to fix this? I have confirmed that the settings on the camera are fine. I need to use ffmpeg for other analysis.

Comment: Can you check with `mediaInfo` if the creation time was actually added to the file? Just because it's on the stream doesn't mean its on the filedata : https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/

Comment: Okay I know what's caused the issue: it's a camera firmware bug.

http://forum.xiaoyi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=37916

thanks though!